# How to iterate through IMongoCollection<> and print all the elements?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I followed this tutorial but the nuget package is old and a new package is used now MongoDB.Driver https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656093/Connecting-MongoDB-with-ASP-NET So the syntax is different and i can itterate through the elements. Here's what I've got till now.

```
List<Info> list = new List<Info>();
var server = new MongoClient(MongoUrl.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
IMongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("DB");
IMongoCollection<Info> valuti = database.GetCollection<Info>("Vals");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use **Find(_=>true)**  method of **IMongoCollection<>** and iterate it

```
List<Info> list = new List<Info>();
var server = new MongoClient(MongoUrl.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
IMongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("DB");
IMongoCollection<Info> valuti = database.GetCollection<Info>("Vals");
    vaulti.Find(_=>true).ToList().ForEach(vault => {
    //Iteration    
 });
```

Comment: I don't think there is Find All method in IMongoCollection

Comment: yeah thats true , they have removed the support for findall in newer versions ... i have updated my answer